# HTML5 validation - is it useful and if yes, is it too raw to use at the moment?

Tags: javascript, forms, html, validation, modernizr

What I've tried successfully -

Use Modernizr to detect Modernizr.input.required, with fallback on custom JavaScript validation if HTML5 validation available. Also had to check for Safari/Opera browser which had unexpected result and had to fall back on custom JavaScript validation as well.

Lastly, I had to also insert a submit button and click on it by JavaScript if I wanted to HTML5 validate, since I want to use an anchor for the form submit button.

With all the trouble of implementing this, as well as inconsistency in validation messages between html5 validate and normal JavaScript validate, is it worth it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all of the major browsers try to implement as standard as possible HTML5, the old browsers will not support it ever, so if your app targets old browsers too it is worth the trouble of extending old browser with a self made library which does the same things as HTML5 and the same function names. If this is not your goal, then it is worth it again because it is a good practise ( with HTML 5 people will forget what javascript torture really is ).

Comment: JavaScript is no torture for me... it is consistent for all browsers. and what is good practise is really subjective, even though I try to use what is new in HTML5.

Comment: I really looking for a few tangible benefits in point form... rather than the general consensus of 'good practise', because what is good practise from 'standards' may not be good practise for user experience or even code maintenance.

Comment: JS torture was just a joke. the consistency in all browsers is again subjective. The answer is simple if you want to have a Cross Browser webApp which uses the full extent of HTML 5 and still be compatible with IE6, for example overloading the Element and Node with the functions you need ( i.e. getElementsByClassName ) and other events, you need to do exactly what you did but with a more complex structure, to be safe on all platforms, so it is worth it.

Comment: code maintenance is easy as long as you code as general as possible and as clean as possible.

Comment: the code is definitely bloated with the need to test for newer browsers (the minority % at the moment) for this implementation. the negatives just seems to outweight any positive you have highlighted. I hope other expert html5 users would have other thoughts about this as well.